# Issues getting 7265AC Bluetooth to connect to devices in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth, intel

I'm unable to connect to bluetooth devices (any I've tried so far).  My system is a dual boot system with Windows 10.  The devices work perfectly in Windows.  Basically, I can pair the devices but I cannot reliable connect to them.  Any time I am able to connect to them, as soon as I try selecting the device in my audio devices menu, it kicks the bluetooth connection out.  I've followed the instructions here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/255509/bluetooth-pairing-on-dual-boot-of-windows-linux-mint-ubuntu-stop-having-to-p/255510#255510 but it did not help.  I'm pretty ignorant when it comes to drivers and such.  Any help is appreciated!

My system:

```
Kernel 4.4.0-53-generic
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
```

Bluetooth Controller is Intel 7265AC

modinfo returns

```
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-53-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000-13.ucode
...
```

(among others).  I have 7265 firmware up to -17 and 7265D firmware up to -21 in my /lib/firmware directory, but I suppose 4.4.0 chooses to use -13.

beersteiner

Comment: The modinfo results for iwlwifi will show the oldest supported firmware that it will use and is for wifi only as bluetooth uses different modules.  See the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-sound/+bug/1577197) and see if the python script will help, it is called a2dp.py

Comment: Thanks Jeremy31.  Finally got around to fiddling with this a bit.  Using the a2dp.py script yielded "Cannot find 'bluez_card.xx_xx_xx_xx_xx_xx' using 'pactl list cards short'.  I've confirmed this result through the command prompt.  I've also verified that I have pulseaudio-module-bluetooth installed.  When I try the command 'pacmd load-module module-bluetooth-discover' it returns 'Module load failed.".   I'll keep fiddling with this, but wanted to update the thread in case someone has seen this before.